# how to merge a single branch to master branch using gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

this is the code to merge the single branch to master branch

```
 from git import Repo
 repo = Repo.clone_from(URL, versionTag)
 merge = repo.git.merge(versionTag)
 repo.git.push('--set-upstream', 'origin', merge)
```

Error : this is the error i am getting.Please help to to merge a single branch to master branch

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Clone.py", line 51, in <module>
    repo.git.push('--set-upstream', 'origin', merge)
  File "/home/igs-lt14/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 545, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/igs-lt14/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 1014, in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
  File "/home/igs-lt14/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 825, in execute
    raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git push --set-upstream origin Updating 271e9b2..6f5fe42
Fast-forward
 simple | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 simple
  stderr: 'fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in Updating 271e9b2..6f5fe42
Fast-forward
 simple | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 simple'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a regular git merge in command line, you would see:

```
$ git merge upstream/master
> Updating a422352..5fdff0f
```

With gitpython, your merge variable got the same kind of result: `Updating 271e9b2..6f5fe42`

Instead of using "`merge`" in your push command, use the default branch master:

```
repo.git.push('--set-upstream', 'origin', "master")
                                          ^^^^^^^^
                                 (instead of merge)
```